# Ruby dynamically updating value in nested array

Tags: arrays, ruby

In Ruby, with a 1D `Array`, I can dynamically select elements by passing an `Integer` key in brackets, as follows:

```rb
example =  [0,1,2,[3,4]]
i = 2

example[i]
==> 2
```

What I would like to achieve, is to dynamically update an element in a multi-dimensional `Array` by passing an `Array` of `Integers`, each representing the index to select in each array. Example of what I'd like to achieve:

```rb
example =  [0,1,2,[3,4]]
path = [3, 1] (corresponds to the 4)

example[*path or some other syntax] = 9
example 
==> [0,1,2,[3,9]]
```

What I've tried is storing the result with each path iteration:

```rb
temp = example
path.each {|index|
  temp = temp[index]
}
temp
==> 4
```

This successfully identifies the element I'd like to update. However, it appears to have stored a copy, rather than to reference the original location, as:

```rb
temp = 9
example
==> [0,1,2,[3,4]]
```

How can I update the base array `example` without hardcoding `path` in individual brackets?

Clarification after a comment: I don't know the `path` length in advance, which is why hardcoding isn't viable.

Comment: `example[3][1] = 9` isn't enough?

Comment: No, as I want to be able to accommodate multiple `path` lengths. Hard-coding with brackets limits me to a 2-step `path`.

Comment: Write a method. Passing in the array object, then indices. You will have to make your method be able to accept any number of indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your iteration is almost there, you just need to stop one step before you run through `path` so that you can have the array you need to modify rather than the element.

So split the `path` into the pieces you want:

```
*p, target = path
# [3], 1
```

Then use `#inject` to find the array:

```
ary = p.inject(example) { |i, a| a[i] }
# [3, 4]
```

and then do your assignment:

```
ary[target] = 9
```

Of course you'll need to add some logic to deal with the unexpected such as `path` leading you to a non-array element or `path` not matching the structure of `example` (consider `path = [11, 6, 23]` in your example).

You could also use `#dig` instead of `#inject`:

```
ary = example.dig(*p)
ary[target] = 9

# or
example.dig(*p)[target] = 9
```

That would take care of some of the problematic `path`s and you'd be left with deciding what to do if `ary.nil?`.

Answer (score 2):

Define a function, something along the lines of:

```rb
def deep_set! val, arr, *path
  path[0...-1].each {|i| arr = arr[i]}
  arr[path[-1]] = val
end
```

```rb
arr =  [0,1,2,[3,4]]
deep_set! 9, arr, 3 ,1

arr #=> [0, 1, 2, [3, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume `path` contains at least one element.

You could use [Array#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-dig).

```
def dig_and_replace(arr, path, replacement)
  *first, last = path
  if first.empty?
    arr[last] = replacement
  else
    arr.dig(*first)[last] = replacement
  end
  arr
end
```

```
arr = [0,1,2,[3,4]]
dig_and_replace(arr,[3,1],99)
  #=> [0,1,2,[3,99]]
arr
  #=> [0,1,2,[3,99]]
```

```
dig_and_replace([0,1,2,[3,             4              ]],[3,1],
  {cat:'meow', dog:'woof'})
  #=>           [0,1,2,[3,{:cat=>"meow", :dog=>"woof"}]]
dig_and_replace([0,[1,[2,3,[4,5,[6, 7],8],9],10,11]],[1,1,2,2,1],99)
  #=>           [0,[1,[2,3,[4,5,[6,99],8],9],10,11]]
dig_and_replace([0,[1,[2,3,[4,5,[6,7],8],9],10,11]],[1,1,2],99)
  #=>           [0,[1,[2,3,     99,      9],10,11]]
```

Note that if

```
path = [1,2,3,4]
*first, last = path
```

then

```
first #=> [1,2,3]
last  #=> 4
```